# using "as" breaks imports in python?

Tags: python, import, module, package

Why does this work fine in python 2.x:

```
>> import matplotlib
>> import matplotlib.pylab
```

while this doesn't?

```
>> import matplotlib as mp
>> import mp.pylab
ImportError: No module named mp.pylab
```

isn't `as` just a short hand/alias for the module being used? it doesn't make sense that the first case works and second doesn't. why does it happen?

you can do same with `os`/`path` (from @kevin):

```
>> import os as o
>> import o.path
ImportError: No module named o.path
```

Comment: Wild guess: `import` is dumb and doesn't use variable name lookup on its identifiers the way you might expect. If this is so, I would guess that `import matplotlib \n xyz = matplotlib \n import xyz.pylab` would also fail, so it's not necessarily the fault of `as` specifically.

Comment: its not the local matplotlib you are importing `matplotlib.pylab` from

Comment: you are importing `matplotlib/pylab.py` .. (or perhaps `matplotlib/pylab/__init__.py`

Comment: For anyone wishing to experiment with this that doesn't have matplotlib, you can use `os` and `path` as replacements for `matplotlib` and `pylab`, and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you say

```
import foo.bar
```

you are essentially describing an import file path it will look for `foo/bar.py` or `foo/bar/__init__.py`

you could mimic this to see by creating

## test.py

```
x=5
```

## test2.py

```
import test.x
```

you will see an error about no module x

this has nothing to do with aliasing imports with `as` nor does it have anything to do with matplotlib ...

it is what the import statement does, it describes where to find the file

ergo when you type

```
import mp.pylab
```

you are telling the filesystem to look for `mp/pylab.py` or `mp/pylab/__init__.py` (of coarse neither of those exists)

#### LARGE DISCLAIMER

this is probably a gross oversimplification

Comment: i never said it has anything to do with matplotlib, i only used it as an example. i'm not sure why you say it has "nothing to do with aliasing imports with ``as``" - this is what causes it. if ``as`` is an alias, then it should know that ``mp.pylab`` is merely short for ``matplotlib.pylab`` and not look for ``mp/pylab`` which is silly, rather look for ``matplotlib.pylab``

Comment: no it doest ... its not using that at all in an import statement ... an import statement describes a _*path*_ to the file  ... you can very easily type `mp.some_method_or_attribute` and everything works ...

Comment: my point is that it's a bug that it's not using the full name before translating the import into a *filename path* when it's loading the modules. i see your point though that it's the fault of ``import`` and not ``as`` keyword

Comment: its not a bug ... its the way the language was designed

Comment: it's not a bug in the sense that it doesn't implement the language correctly. it's a bug in the sense of poor design / bad behavior...

Comment: well you should talk to @Kevin about that... he is writing his own language and maybe he can avoid that pitfall (on a side note you can file a bug with python and maybe they will decide to change it(I doubt it)) or you could write your own language(its not that hard theres libraries to help ... well its kinda hard) ... python is also open source so you can just fix it for yourself if you want

Comment: In regards to design, I see it as a kind of rock and a hard place issue. If you treat the identifiers in an `import` statement as though they were variables, then `import os.path` would give `NameError: name 'os' is not defined` because it won't find anything when it does a name lookup for `os` in order to see if it's an alias. That may be partly why the identifiers in the `import` statement are treated as literal strings.